# Swift: "unrecognised selector sent to instance" both with/without delegate

Tags: swift, delegates

** Everything described below was done programmatically. No use of StoryBoard **

In my ViewController I create a CustomCheckBoxContainer that contains buttons and labels. (labels not shown here!!) I've added actions to the buttons and as long as I address a function in a child (eg. CustomCheckBoxContainer and CustomCheckBox) the wether is shiny and bright. However, when trying to add an action that calls a function in ViewController, clouds start to form above my project.

Error message: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView buttonClicked3:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...'.

Button action:

```
newButton.addTarget(currentView, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonClicked3(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Then realised you can't sent data or actions back upstream. So created protocol and delegate and rewritten the action to:

```
newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(delegate3.buttonClicked3(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

.  Unfortunately, exact same result.

I'm completely stuck. What am I not seeing?

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ButtonClicked3Delegate  {

 @objc func buttonClicked3(sender: UIButton) {
       print ("Action received in the ViewController Class")
    }

let userArray: [String] = ["one","two”]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for item in userArray {
        let customCheckBoxContainer = CustomCheckBoxContainer()
        customCheckBoxContainer.showNewButton(..args.., currentView: UIView, ... args ...)
        self.view.addSubview(customCheckBoxContainer)
    }
  }
}
```

CustomCheckBoxContainer.swift:

```
    @objc protocol ButtonClicked3Delegate {
    @objc func buttonClicked3(sender: UIButton)
    //other data needed
}

class CustomCheckBoxContainer: UIView {
    var newButton: CustomCheckBox!

    var delegate3 : ButtonClicked3Delegate!

    func showNewButton (... args...  currentView: UIView, ... args ... ) {
        newButton = CustomCheckBox (type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        newButton.bounds = ...
        newButton.center = ...

        newButton.addTarget(newButton, action: #selector(CustomCheckBox.buttonClicked1(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        newButton.addTarget(self, action:     #selector(CustomCheckBoxContainer.buttonClicked2(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        newButton.addTarget(self, action:     #selector(delegate3.buttonClicked3(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        currentView.addSubview(newButton)

    }

    func buttonClicked2(sender:UIButton) {
        print ("Action received in the CustomCheckBoxContainer Class")
    }
}
```

CustomCheckBox.swift

```
class CustomCheckBox: UIButton {

    func buttonClicked1(sender:UIButton) {
        print ("Action was received in CustomCheckBox Class")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split it into two stages.

Link the button to a selector in the child view controller (the following is Swift 2.3 syntax) along the following lines:

```
button.addTarget(self, action #selector(self.buttonTapped()), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Then call the delegate method from within your implementation of buttonTapped(_:):

```
func buttonTapped() -> Void {
    Self.delegate.buttonWasTapped()
    ...
}
```

[Incidentally, check also that the delegate is not nil. You've declared it as an implicitly unwrapped optional which is correct, but this means you need to set the delegate from the parent view controller.]

Comment: That was a great tip. Makes thinks more readable too. So I implemented it as suggested. In the end, the solution seemed to be (as you predicted) that delegate was indeed "nil".   I overlooked to assign a value it in the ViewController. So problem solved after adding the following statement to func viewDidLoad:   " CheckBoxContainer.delegate = self".